# Presenting a user hierarchy in CRM Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, dynamics-crm

I've been attempting to show the tile version of user hierarchy that Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 provides to the system admins.

At first I just presented a web resource of the users personal wall with a view that included all the details(date hired, full name, title, email, etc) for `@me` but then I looked into the console and saw the code that holds this tile version. So I tried using it as a web resource within CRM to present it in the dashboard but although it loads up, its not dynamic. If I make a change to someone's manager, this change will not be reflected in the web resource.

I've been looking for approaches for about 3 days now but no one seems to be doing this. This is just a side project but now I kind of really wanna accomplish it. So SO is my last resource right now.

Web programming is not my strongest suit so I haven't been able to crack everything the source code has to use it a reference for my own solution.